# When to use "as" and what is the exact meaning of it

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning

> "Show them who the new boss in town is, and make quick work of them as Evie catches up to you."

What is the meaning of "as" here? And is there any other way to describe it without using as?

Comment: Can you give more context, please? I just don't understand the what the words after as mean.

Comment: I just don't know how to use "as" in a sentence.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to tell without more context, but it looks like "as" is being used to mean "while" or "during the time that".  That is, you could rephrase this sentence like this:

> During the time that Evie is catching up to you, you should show them who the new boss is and make quick work of them.

It sounds to me like Evie is some sort of future rival, and the advice is to establish your dominance over everyone else early so that you will have no other rivals distracting you by the time that Evie catches up and threatens you directly.